# Can I set up an Apple TV to receive content from a Synology NAS?

Tags: itunes, audio, appletv, airport, nas

I have a [Synology DS210j NAS](http://www.synology.com/enu/products/DS210j/index.php). My music and movies are served from the NAS by its built-in iTunes server. The content is then available on my MacBook in iTunes / Sharing Library.

I am looking for a way to set up an audio system in my apartment that doesn't need my MacBook. The content would come from the NAS (served by the iTunes server).

I'd like to buy a 2nd generation AppleTV to receive the content and then use iPhone's Remote app to control it. I also thought about extending this setup with AirPlay speakers (probably with an Airport Express) which would allow me to control the music separately in every room.

Would such a setup work? Can an AppleTV receive content from the NAS/iTunes server? If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Watch Erica Sadun's [AirFlick](http://ericasadun.com/ftp/AirPlay/) project. It can do what you want from a host running Mac OS X, so one would expect a GUI-less version to appear soon that could be ported to your NAS.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware a stock AppleTV will only talk to the iTunes store or a Mac/PC running iTunes. Third party daapd servers such as the one that Synology embed in their NAS line won't work without hacking the AppleTV. Currently the hacks for the black AppleTV are just getting started but Firecore have mentioned being able to play almost any media file from almost any NAS in a upcoming update. See:
http://firecore.com/atvflash-black

> **Access Media Anywhere**
>   Stream media
>   from most NAS devices. Includes
>   support for AFP, SMB and NFS
>   protocols.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used my Synology NAS directly with my two AppleTVs.  There are two different options that I've had success with.

1. [iTunes Home Sharing](http://originwww.synology.com/dsm/itunes_server.php?lang=us)
2. [Synology AirPlay support](http://originwww.synology.com/dsm/airplay.php?lang=us) and told it to use the audio renderer that is the AppleTV.

Note, you have to be using at least DSM 3.2.  Also, I've seen a few problems where it didn't like to play Apple Lossless files via home sharing.

Answer (score 1):

the apple TV works only with airplay (old airtunes) protocol, which is proprietary and does not allow to do streaming from any other 3rd party devices which includes synology nas severs (and other devices).